# Mount Ubuntu Partition Within Windows

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, macrium

I've installed Ubuntu alongside Windows. I can boot into either using GRUB. In Ubuntu, I can see my entire bootdrive, and all of its partitions, including my windows partition and system files which I really don't want to write to.

However, in Windows, the partition Ubuntu is installed to is completely hidden.

I have a backup imaging program called Macrium that is routinely backs up all partitions on my drive to an external disk.

However, I can't select the Ubuntu partition to be part of the backup. I want it to be part of the backup so I can clone my disk inorder to transfer to a new storage device, or do a complete restore.

My question is, how can I select these partitions within Macrium, or, if you're not familiar with Macrium, how do I make my Ubuntu partition visible within Windows? I feel that will fix my problem as I can see all partitions within macrium that I can see within Window's file explorer.

Comment: Windows can't see ubuntu/linux partitions by design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an additional Windows driver. e.g.

- [ExtFS](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/extfs-windows)
- [Ext2FSD](http://www.ext2fsd.com)